# Can't pass arguments to class methods, when using them in a promise callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, arrow-functions

I have a class:

```
'use strict';
class aClass {
    a() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (1 != 1) {
                reject(new Error('error'));
            } else {
                resolve('a');
            }
        });
    }
    b(b) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (1 != 1) {
                reject(new Error('error'));
            } else {
                resolve('b');
            }
        });
    }
    c(c) {
        console.log(c);
    }


    do()  {
        this.a()
            .then((a) => {
                this.b(a);
            })
            .then((b) => {
                console.log(b);
                this.c(b);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('err', error);
            });
    }
}

module.exports = aClass;
```

When I create the object of the class and call `do()` method:

```
let anObject = new aClass();
anObject.do();
```

*"undefined"* is logged twice in the console. It means that in the `b()` method arguments are no passed to a promise resolve: `resolve('b');`

Meanwhile, if I do not use class method, but add code directly into the callback:

```
do()  {
    this.a()
        .then((a) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (1 != 1) {
                    reject(new Error('error'));
                } else {
                    resolve('b');
                }
            });
        })
        .then((b) => {
            console.log(b);
            this.c(b);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('err', error);
        });
}
```

Everything is ok, *"b"* is logged twice in the console.

I am using `nodejs` for this example and `babeljs` as a transpiler. 
Why arguments are not passed when I use class method? Are there any scope restrictions, or it is a transpiler issue?

Comment: if you `return this.b(a);` it's all good, or remove the {} around `this.b(a)` it works as expected again ... learn arrow function syntax to know why this is

Comment: Thanks, indeed I forgot to return a thenable object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
.then((a) => {
  this.b(a);
})
```

you're not `return`ing anything, so `undefined` is returned instead - that's goes into

```
.then((b) => {
   console.log(b);
   this.c(b);
})
```

that both logs it and passes it into `c`, which also logs it.

Try changing your code to:

```
.then((a) => {
  return this.b(a);
})
```